# numbered rows in datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex3, rows

I am creating an app where users input their investment info into a datagrid on each row one row at a time. As they move along new rows are dynamically generated so they can input new investments. As the user moves and puts in new info I want a column to display what row the user is on (or better said what number investment he is on). I had an idea about the how to create the function:

```
private function rowCount():void
      {
        myDG.dataProvider=tasks;
        myDG.rowCount=tasks.length;
        }
```

but Im just not sure how to implement it in the datagrid.

How would I implement something like that? What datagrid property would I use? Im still fairly new to flex 3 so any help is appreciated!

```
<mx:DataGrid id="myDG"

 width="908" height="410" 
dataProvider="{tasks}" 
sortableColumns="false" editable="true"
itemEditBeginning="checkEdit(event)" 

itemEditEnd="editEnd(event)" x="10" y="0" >
<mx:columns>
  <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Investment number" 
    dataField="investment number "  width="80">

  <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Symbol" 
    dataField="symbol"  width="105">
    </mx:DataGridColumn>
   <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Trade Date" 
    dataField="date"  width="80">

</mx:DataGridColumn>
</mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting simply, you need to display the index of the row in itemRenderer.

Look at this question and answers, the problem and its solution are the same (since `List` and `DataGrid` derives from the same `ListBase`):

[Display List ItemRenderer Index in Flex3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911054/display-list-itemrenderer-index-in-flex3/)